# Axially symmetric solution of a PDE on $S^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

> Suppose  $u$ is a smooth solution of the following PDE on $S^2$:
> $$
> -\frac{1}{3}\Delta_{S^2} u+1=e^{2u}.
> $$
> Prove that the PDE only admits a constant solution, i.e., $u\equiv 0$ on $S^2$.

With loss of generality, we can assume $u=u(x_3)$, and by the classic stereographic projection, we can transform the PDE to an ODE in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus to prove the result, we may rely on some energy estimate for a function related to $u$. I believe a candidate function could be $G(x_3)=(1-x_3)\partial_{x_3}u$. But I am stucked in the process.

Could you give some suggestions? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Which sign convention are you using on $\Delta_{\mathbb S^2}$? If you are using the 'usual one' ($\Delta_{\mathbb S^2}=\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}u )$) then I don't immediatley see the answer, but if you use the other convention ($\Delta_{\mathbb S^2}=-\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}u )$) then this follows quickly from analysing what happens at max/min points

Comment: Here I use convention such that $-\Delta_{S^2}$ has positive eigenvalues. I think it is worthwhile to have your answer at the answer section. Thanks!